# CloudFront and S3 for video optimism

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

CloudFront and S3 are ready and I can get CloudFront url related video files.
I have to render video file on mobile app, but in bad network condition, its screen turns in black very often due to its slow network connection.
Can CloudFront support video optimism when saves media file into s3?
If not, how can I solve this problem?

Video optimism with S3 and CloudFront

Comment: You can create multiple streams with a service like Elemental MediaConvert and serve them with a solution like HLS or MPEG-DASH that allows the player to adapt to network condtions.  See this [white papaer](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/amazon-cloudfront-for-media.pdf) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/introduction.html) to convert or optimize your video files stored in an S3 bucket to formats suitable for mobile devices

> Amazon Elastic Transcoder lets you convert media files that you have stored in Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) into media files in the formats required by consumer playback devices. For example, you can convert large, high-quality digital media files into formats that users can play back on mobile devices,

you want to use Amazon Elastic Transcoder for video optimization, Amazon S3 for storing video files and Amazon CloudFront for distributing the optimized videos close to your users

> Using Amazon Elastic Transcoder, >Amazon S3 and Amazon CloudFront, you >can store, transcode and deliver >your >content. By setting the S3 >permissions >for your CloudFront >distribution in >Amazon Elastic >Transcoder, it is now a >simple one >step process to transcode >content >with Amazon Elastic Transcoder >and deliver the multiple output videos >via progressive download or adaptive >bitrate streaming (HLS, Smooth, or >MPEG-DASH) with CloudFront.